# Problemas al trabajar caracteres convertir caracteres

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de trabajar con los caracteres comilla simple (') y con la barra invertida (\) y trabajarlos como un string o por lo menos reconocer estos caracteres como un string que viene en un textBox.

Trato de hacer esto:

```
Cifrado['\'] = 'p';
Cifrado['''] = 'd';
```

Pero me da un problema de conversión de UTF-16. Hay algún código con el cual pueda trabajar estos caracteres especiales?

Comment: Hola, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay ciertos tipos de caracteres especiales cuyo tratamiento debe ser diferente a caracteres digamos "convencionales", entre estos caracteres especiales se incluyen la **comilla simple (')**, **comilla doble (")**, **barra invertida (\)**, y otros más. Para solucionar tu problema puedes anteponer una **barra invertida (\)** al carácter especial:

```
"\\" //Imprime la barra invertida
"\'" //Imprime la comilla simple
"\"" //Imprime la comilla doble
```

En el caso de que tu **string** tenga varios caracteres especiales sería engorroso anteponer la barra invertida:

```
"\\a\\b\\e" //Imprime a\b\e
```

Por tanto se recomienda anteponer el **caracter de arroba (@)** delante del **string**:

```
@"a\b\e" //Imprime a\b\e
```

También puedes usar directamente el **código ASCII** del caracter:

```
(char)39 //Imprime la comilla simple ya que en el código ASCII el número **39** corresponde a la comilla simple.
```

Tu solución podría quedar de esta forma:

```
Cifrado['\\'] = 'p';
Cifrado['\''] = 'd';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Nota: no es necesario escapar las comillas simples en un string `"''"` ni las comillas dobles en un carácter `'"'`.

Comment: @Mateo a partir de qué versión de c# es eso?

Comment: No sé exactamente pero funciona https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/v7Q4My9dIbiyuCQ115orOSexuFghoCg/vSgxV6GaSwEIiksSSzKTFcryM1MUfBMz8zSKS4qAeqJjFRKL0os1gao4nfPzivNzUvXCizJLUn0y81I1lNSVNK3B2kEAU15dSR0qX8tV@/8/AA

Comment: Al menos desde .NET Framework 4.7